# NZEC Java error in some cases

Tags: java

The relevant code is simple, and without many arithmetic operations, still I am not able to find the part throwing NZEC.
The input from the buffered reader seems fine, there's no division, so division by zero is eliminated as the possible cause.
There are no infinite loops as well (i guess).

I still cannot find the problem. Here's the code:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.util.Arrays;

class feb152 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int i;
        int[] piles = new int[100000];

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System. in ));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        int t = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        while (t != 0) {
            st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            int n = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            Arrays.fill(piles, 0);
            st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int coins = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                piles[coins]++;
            }
            int max = 0;
            for (int val: piles) {
                if (val > max) {
                    max = val;
                }
            }
            int ans = n - max;
            System.out.print(ans + "\n");
            t--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify, NZEC = ??

Comment: Describe in more detail exactly what is wrong. What test do you do and what fails. If it's an exception, show the message and stack trace.

Comment: actually its a test case in codechef.thats why i dont know in which case NZEC is coming/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NZEC means "Non zero exit code". Its essentially saying that your program ran into some error during execution. Mostly, it comes up when there is a **"Segmentation Fault"**.

Ref : http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-various-reasons-that-can-cause-NZEC-error-in-codechef-and-spoj

Comment: i have read this already.but nothing is coming.i have put the whole code.if u can tell in the code!!

Comment: can you also give the question's URL ??