# "NZEC" error in Java code during online submission

Tags: java

When I run the following code (in system compiler) it works well, but when I submitted it to the site, all test cases throw nzec runtime error. Unfortunately the site does not share test cases but they can be created using the question.

Can any one please explain why there is a nzec error? I have used java so code is throwing an exception that needs to be caught:

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument.Iterator;

public class Readinput1 {

public static int readinput () throws IOException
{
    //InputStreamReader r=new InputStreamReader(System.in);  
    //BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(r);  
      int n1=0;
      int name=0;
    System.out.println("Enter num");  
    //name=br.read(); 
//  if (name!=null){
    // n1=Integer.parseInt(name.trim());
     //     }
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    name= in.nextInt();

    return name;

}


  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 int num=0;

 ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (num!=42)
            {
        num=readinput();

                al.add(num);


            }
    //Iterator itr=(Iterator) al.iterator();
    //while(((java.util.Iterator<Integer>) itr).hasNext()){ 
    al.remove(al.size()-1);
    //  String num1=itr.toString();
           //System.out.println(num1);  

     for (Integer integer : al) {
          System.out.println(integer);
        }
          }  


      }
```

Comment: Please provide the complete error message.

Comment: runtime error (NZEC)

Comment: `NZEC` doesn't help. Please describing `I submitted it to the site` more. Are you on http://www.codechef.com/ or similar?

Comment: `NZEC`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28406831/4956096

Comment: It was in spoj , the problem is to get input integers and stop if input is 42.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are any reason throwing exceptions and produce a so called `NZCE`.

I don't give you the solution but pointing on some critical parts.

- `int n1=Integer.parseInt(name);` - think about `name` is not a valid `Integer`
- `al.remove(al.size()-1);` - what's about the size of `al` is **0**

Comment: now I have modified code to get integer ,but still error persists. for al.remove(al,size()-1); we are getting input upto number is !42 .so always size is greater than 1.

Answer (score -1):

Use exception handling

```
try{

// code which you think might throw an exception

}catch(Exception t){

// you got the exception. Now what??

}
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem. And not sure it will help to debug something, unless you can output something to the console.

Comment: after catch just put (Exception e )